# Turing invariance on large sets

Tags: logic, set-theory, computability, descriptive-set-theory

**Definition:** A function $f: 2^{\omega} \rightarrow 2^{\omega}$ is Turing invariant if $x \equiv_T y \rightarrow f(x)\equiv_T f(y)$.

**Question I (under $ZFC$):** Let $f: 2^{\omega} \rightarrow 2^{\omega}$ be a Borel function, is there necessarily a set $A$ of positive Lebesgue measure such that $f\restriction A$ is Turing invariant?

**Remark**: Assuming the axiom of choice, it's easy to construct a non-Borel counterexample, so I suspect that the answer to the question might have something to do with the interplay of choice-pathologies-definability, therefore I'm also interested in the following question:

**Question II:** Same as the previous question, but in choiceless models where we have regularity properties for all sets of reals (e.g. Solovay's model and $AD$ models).

Comment: Wow, you really got desperate with that, eh?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: A constant function is necessarily Turing invariant, so it's not a counterexample.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Indeed, so if for all $x$, $f(x)=a$ for a constant $a$, then trivially $x\equiv_T y \rightarrow f(x)=a\equiv_T a=f(y)$.

Comment: Bah, I'm failing logic (or else I thought it was $\leftrightarrow$ rather than $\to$). Move along, nothing to see here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Life is too short for questions outside of my fields of research. ;)

Comment: Isn't set theory your field of research, and nowadays set theory with respect to measurability with respect to all sort of ideals? This seems like a question right up your alley.

Comment: Along the same lines, Turing cones have Lebesgue measure zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f:2^{\omega} \to 2^{\omega}$ be projection on even coordinates: $f(x) = x_0$ where $x = x_0 \oplus x_1$. Suppose $A \subseteq 2^{\omega}$ is compact and has positive measure. WLOG, we can assume that for every $x \in A$, $x_0$ is Turing incomparable with $x_1$. Using Lebesgue density, choose $\sigma, \tau \in 2^{k}$, $k < \omega$ such that $A$ has, say, more than $99$ percent measure in $[\sigma \oplus \tau]$. Since $A$ has high density in $\sigma \oplus \tau$, we can choose $x \in 2^{\omega}$ such that both $y = \sigma x_0 \oplus \tau x_1$ and $z = \sigma x_1 \oplus \tau x_0$ are in $A$. But $y, z$ have same Turing degrees while $f(y) = \sigma x_0$ and $f(z) = \sigma x_1$ are not even Turing comparable.

Comment: He said that he asked everyone this question today, and you give him an answer here? Amusing! :-)

Comment: He didn't ask me.

Comment: Tsk tsk tsk, shame on him.

Comment: @hot_queen: Why is the "WLOG" true?

Comment: Because the set of $x \in 2^{\omega}$ for which $x_0, x_1$ are Turing comparable is null (by Fubini's theorem).

Comment: @hot_queen: Got it. Nice solution, thanks!